# do not know how to convert 'x' to class “Date”

Tags: r

I'm writing this code in R but not able to solve this error.

```
L <- read_csv('C:\\Users\\Documents\\LaptopSales.csv',col_names = TRUE)
Dates=as.Date(L[,2],format = "%m/%d/%Y")    <--- this keeps me showing an error
tab=data.frame(Dates,L$Retail.Price)
tab$Month=as.Date(cut(Dates,breaks="month"))
head(tab$Month)
```

Output

```
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  Date = col_character(),
  Configuration = col_double(),
  `Customer Postcode` = col_character(),
  Store.Postcode = col_character(),
  Retail.Price = col_double(),
  `Screen Size (Inches)` = col_double(),
  `Battery Life (Hours)` = col_double(),
  `RAM (GB)` = col_double(),
  `Processor Speeds (GHz)` = col_double(),
  `Integrated Wireless?` = col_character(),
  `HD Size (GB)` = col_double(),
  `Bundled Applications?` = col_character(),
  `customer X` = col_double(),
  `customer Y` = col_double(),
  `store X` = col_double(),
  `store Y` = col_double()
)
```

> Error in as.Date.default(x, ...) : do not know how to convert 'x' to class “Date”

Data

```
dput(head(L))

structure(list(Date = c("1/1/2008 0:01", "1/1/2008 0:02", "1/1/2008 0:04", 
"1/1/2008 0:04", "1/1/2008 0:06", "1/1/2008 0:12"), Configuration = c(163, 
320, 23, 169, 365, 309), `Customer Postcode` = c("EC4V 5BH", 
"SW4 0JL", "EC3V 1LR", "SW1P 3AU", "EC4V 4EG", "W1B 5PX"), Store.Postcode = c("SE1 2BN", 
"SW12 9HD", "E2 0RY", "SE1 2BN", "SW1V 4QQ", "SW1V 4QQ"), Retail.Price = c(455, 
545, 515, 395, 585, 555), `Screen Size (Inches)` = c(15, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15), `Battery Life (Hours)` = c(5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 6), 
    `RAM (GB)` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1), `Processor Speeds (GHz)` = c(2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2), `Integrated Wireless?` = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", 
    "No", "No", "Yes"), `HD Size (GB)` = c(80, 300, 300, 40, 
    120, 120), `Bundled Applications?` = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), `customer X` = c(532041, 529240, 533095, 
    529902, 531684, 529207), `customer Y` = c(180995, 175537, 
    181047, 179641, 180948, 180969), `store X` = c(534057, 528739, 
    535652, 534057, 528924, 528924), `store Y` = c(179682, 173080, 
    182961, 179682, 178440, 178440)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Not sure how to fix this. I looked at all other solution available online but not able to fix it.
Please help. Thanks

Comment: Share your data using `dput(head(L))`

Comment: posted in original post

Comment: Shouldn’t it be L[,1] since the Date is the first column and not the second?

Comment: I tried L[,1] as well but getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `as.Date` :

```
L$Date <- as.Date(L$Date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```

Comment: Thank for the reply. but when I ran your code I'm getting is -> [1] "2008-01-01" "2008-01-01" "2008-01-01" "2008-01-01" "2008-01-01" "2008-01-01" 

But I should be getting -> ## [1] "2008-09-01" "2008-05-01" "2008-12-01" "2008-09-01" "2008-11-01"
## [6] "2008-08-01"

I'm not getting expected output. not sure whats wrong here.

Comment: @SagarC Did you check `L$Date` ? It is `"1/1/2008 0:01" "1/1/2008 0:02" "1/1/2008 0:04"` why should you get `"2008-09-01" "2008-05-01" "2008-12-01"` ?

Comment: @RonakShah I guess he is pointing out the final output i.e `head(tab$Month)` in his code.

Comment: Yes. I'm referring to final output. Code that you gave me it solved the error. but I'm not getting the expected output which is given in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced a similar error and copying it to a different variable had helped me. I am not sure if it will help you. You can just give it a try.

```
a <- L$Date
Dates <- as.Date(a,format = "%m/%d/%Y")
month <- as.Date(cut(Dates,breaks="month"))
```

Comment: It doesnt give me an error, But output is not what it should be when I run this code. 
Output -> 
"2008-01-01" "2008-01-01" "2008-01-01" "2008-01-01" "2008-01-01" "2008-01-01"

Expected Output->
## [1] "2008-09-01" "2008-05-01" "2008-12-01" "2008-09-01" "2008-11-01"
## [6] "2008-08-01"

Not sure what else needs to be change in the code that I pasted here in my original post.

Comment: @SagarC Are you referring to the final output? `head(tab$Month)` this one?

Comment: @SagarC How many unique months are there in your dataset?

Comment: Yes. I'm referring to final output head(tab$Month). Which is not correct.

Comment: I have made some edits. What does `month` give you here?

Comment: I'm not sure how to clean the duplicate entries since there is time given in the same column. there are 29k total entries. not sure how to find unique months in dataset.

Comment: What does `month` give you here?

Comment: your updated codes gives exactly same output as it was giving me before. at the end of execution of all original code it should give me 

## [1] "2008-09-01" "2008-05-01" "2008-12-01" "2008-09-01" "2008-11-01"
## [6] "2008-08-01"

I have no clue where does this comes from.

Comment: I'm trying to execute code from this link: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/532920_3c66ade02a684b18a0f94b210621b0e4.html

I hope this will help you to understand the problem.

Comment: @SagarC I understand. It'll be easy for me if you could provide me with a sample of the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lubridate`

```
 library(lubridate)
 L$Date <- mdy_hm(L$Date)
```